# Recreating JS bitwise integer handling in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, hash, integer, binary-operators

I need to translate a hash function from JavaScript to Python.

The function is as follows:

```js
function getIndex(string) {
        var length = 27;
        string = string.toLowerCase();
        var hash = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
                hash = string.charCodeAt(i) + (hash << 6) + (hash << 16) - hash;
        }
        var index = Math.abs(hash % length);
        return index;
}

console.log(getIndex(window.prompt("Enter a string to hash")));
```

This function is Objectively Correct™. It is perfection itself. I can't change it, I just have to recreate it. Whatever it outputs, my Python script must also output.

However - I'm having a couple of problems, and I think that it's all to do with the way that the two languages handle signed integers.

JS bitwise operators treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits. Python, however, has no concept of bit limitation and just keeps going like an absolute madlad. I think that this is the one relevant difference between the two languages.

I can limit the length of `hash` in Python by masking it to 32 bits with `hash & 0xFFFFFFFF`.

I can also negate `hash` if it's above `0x7FFFFFFF` with `hash = hash ^ 0xFFFFFFFF` (or `hash = ~hash` - they both seem to do the same thing). I believe that this simulates negative numbers.

I apply both of these restrictions to the hash with a function called `t`.

Here's my Python code so far:

```py
def nickColor(string):
    length = 27

    def t(x):
        x = x & 0xFFFFFFFF
        if x > 0x7FFFFFFF:
            x = x ^ 0xFFFFFFFF
        return x

    string = string.lower()
    hash = t(0)
    for letter in string:
        hash = t(hash)
        hash = t(t(ord(letter)) + t(hash << 6) + t(hash << 16) - t(hash))
    index = hash % length
    return index
```

It seems to work up until the point that a hash needs to become negative, at which point the two scripts diverge. This normally happens about 4 letters into the string.

I'm assuming that my problem lies in recreating JS negative numbers in Python. How can I say bye to this problem?

Comment: All numbers in JavaScript are 64-bit (double-precision) floating point numbers, but [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits.

Comment: @Andreas - thanks for the info, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: how long can these strings get?

Comment: `x ^ 0xFFFFFFFF` doesn't negate the value, it inverts it. The difference is an off by 1 error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a working translation:

```python
def nickColor(string):
    length = 27

    def t(x):
        x &= 0xFFFF_FFFF
        if x > 0x7FFF_FFFF:
            x -= 0x1_0000_0000
        return float(x)

    bytes = string.lower().encode('utf-16-le')
    hash = 0.0
    for i in range(0, len(bytes), 2):
        char_code = bytes[i] + 256*bytes[i+1]
        hash = char_code + t(int(hash) << 6) + t(int(hash) << 16) - hash
    return int(hash % length if hash >= 0 else abs(hash % length - length))
```

The point is, only the shifts (`<<`) are calculated as 32-bit integer operations, their result is [converted back to double](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) before entering additions and subtractions. I'm not familiar with the rules for double-precision floating point representation in the two languages, but it's safe to assume that on all personal computing devices and web servers it is the same for both languages, namely [double-precision IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). For very long strings (thousands of characters) the hash could lose some bits of precision, which of course affects the final result, but in the same way in JS as in Python (not what the author of the Objectively Correct™ function intended, but that's the way it is…). The last line corrects for the different definition of the `%` operator for negative operands in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) and [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).

Furthermore (thanks to Mark Ransom for reminding me this), to fully emulate JavaScript, it is also necessary to consider its encoding, which is UTF-16, but with [surrogate pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U+010000_to_U+10FFFF) handled as if they consisted of 2 characters. Encoding the string as `utf-16-le` you make sure that the first byte in each 16-bit “word” is the least significant one, plus, you don't get the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) that you would get if you used `utf-16` tout court (thank you Martijn Pieters).

Comment: You might need an `encode` of the string to be 100% exact. I don't know enough about Javascript to say for sure.

Comment: Your code assumes that encoding to UTF-16 gives you data in little-endian order, but that’s actually platform dependant. It may work on Windows but on other platforms you could get the opposite ordering! You need to explicitly encode to `utf-16-le`; that ensures that you always get Little Endian byte order data on all platforms and lets you avoid  skipping the first two bytes

Comment: Next, if you wrap the UTF-16 bytes in a [`memoryview` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) you can [cast the data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview.cast) to an iterable of unsigned shorts, removing the need to take two bytes at a time: `for char_code in memoryview(utf16bytes).cast('<H'):`

Comment: You may be able to just stick with encoding to UTF-16 (with BOM) and then use `'@H'` for native byte order traversal, that’ll be faster on platforms where Big Endian is the native byte order. I’m pretty sure that the UTF-16 encoder sticks with the native order preference. Then just slice off the BOM from the memory view cast. Demo: https://ideone.com/JlxUOQ

Comment: Thank you, @MartijnPieters, I didn't expect Python to behave in a platform-dependent way regarding UTF-16, but it may make sense. I fixed the code. Regarding the `memoryview`, you are right that this would be faster, but it would also cause _even more_ head scratching, so I'll wait for a green light from the OP (@snazzybouche) regarding this matter.

Comment: I find the byte multiplying just as head-scratching :-) A memoryview on the other hand may be more familiar to people with a C or Numpy background. As always, a comment to cover the reasons to use it should clear any confusion.

Comment: Small code-review comments: I'd move the `int()` and `float()` conversions both into a bitshift function, and you could use a modulo operation to simulate overflow: `(intval + 0x8000_0000) % 0x1_0000_0000 - 0x8000_0000`: `def js_lshift(f, s): return float(((int(f) << s) + 0x8000_0000) % 0x1_0000_0000 - 0x8000_0000)`.

Comment: Also, `%` in Javascript is the remainder operator (and not modulo, like in Python). `def js_remainder(a, b): a - (int(a / b) * b)` would better reflect this, and use `return int(abs(js_remainder(hash, length)))`. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/743fe1729282784fab55658bc7f347d5) for my rewrite. Not sure why I got so hooked to this little puzzle, but there you have it ;-)